# What is Mathematica's comment-to-line-end token?

Tags: front-end, comment

How can I make a full line of code into a comment by typing a *single* character inserted at start of the line?

In other programming languages I can use characters such as ! , # and language processor will ignore what follows to next newline. I think using `(* ... *)` is a bit shoddy because it takes *six* keystrokes.

Comment: What exactly is a **line** ?:D

Comment: It is what it is. Use a keyboard macro if typing causes such grief. Use a different language if even the thought of it troubles you.

Comment: @bel, depends. How wide is your monitor? ;)

Comment: I guess you don't know this: select something, press Alt + /, and presto!

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. In a more serious mood, this also shook me when I was starting with Mma.  Discovering that there are no  _line_  nor [_delimiter_](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/193)  concepts made a mind blowing day then.

Comment: Exempting any data or text of one code line  from execution with a single start character like( ! ) is common in several softwares, I thought.

Comment: @Narasimham Mathematica is unique in **many** ways. Some of them are sketched [**here**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/193), just in case you haven't seen it

Comment: But, as already noted, since *Mathematica* has no concept of lines *per se*, you cannot have a comment through a unary switch; you need to enclose whatever it is you want to comment out into *something*.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem to be completely transparent. E.g. `1 [return] 2` assigns `In[1]:=1` and `In[2]:=2`, so a linebreak is respected. However, `3[4, [return] 5]` assigns `In[3]:=3[4,5]`, so here it isn't. It seems, though, for all intents and purposes, where a line is handled as a "separate line" it is also a separate input.

Comment: I extremely rarely type in `(* *)`, but use right-click *Un/Comment*.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, as a note, that is actually relatively new behavior (although exactly when that was introduced escapes me). Many an old hand forgot to put a semicolon where they should've and were subsequently mystified by errors saying they multiplied two things they shouldn't have, or have made a recursive definition, or a number of other related errors.

Answer (score 5):

*Mathematica* does not support any kind of comment-to-line-end specaial character(s). You will have to resign yourself to living with that. It does support a very useful and easy to apply block un/commenting feature.

I am running on OS X, so the keyboard shortcut for the context (mouse-right-click) menu's Un/Comment command is <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. I use that do any kind of line or block un/commenting. Here is how it works.

Suppose I have a line that looks this this

[image: uncommented]

When I click anywhere in the line sufficiently many times (three times will do it if I click on `data`) and type <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, it changes to

[image: commented]

When I triple-click on the left-most parenthesis three-times, it reverts back to

[image: uncommented]